# Python simple bouncing physics

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I was wondering if there's a straightforward way to implement bouncing physics in Python, without any modules that do physics. By bouncing physics, I don't mean with gravity, I mean more like the recently released iOS game "Okay?" by Philipp Stollenmayer (https://appsto.re/us/1N7v5.i). I know that if a ball hits straight edges, its velocities are inverted. So, given this diagram:
[image]
When the ball hits A and C, its X velocities are inverted, and when it hits B and D, its Y velocities are inverted. But what if our diagram looks like this:
[image]
Given the angle of the platform, how can I find the new X and Y velocities? Also, how can I convert these X and Y velocities into degrees?

What I found out from Wikipedia is that the bounce's line of symmetry is perpendicular to the surface it hits.

My final question is how, in pygame, to find the angle of a line, and create a line with a certain angle.

Comment: http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/AngleofReflection.html

Comment: you can't really do math without math...

Comment: Look, guys, bouncy physics is not some kind of ancient secret guarded for generation, so you might as well give the answer.

Comment: lol @ "no trigonometry"

Comment: Oops. Do I need trig :( I'm not great at math, being in 9th grade math and all...

Comment: Yes, any time you introduce angles trigonometry is sure to follow. Have a go at some of the khan academy lessons on simple trig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reflectedVector = velocityVector - scale(surfaceNormal, 2.0*dot(surfaceNormal, velocityVector))`

`velocityVector` is movement speed, represented by Vector, moving towards surface.
`surfaceNormal` is perpendicular to the surface, with length of 1.

`dot` is [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). `dot(v1, v2) = v1.x*v2.x + v1.y*v2.y`

`scale` is vector "scale" operation. `scale(inVec, scalar) = vector2d(inVec.x*scalar, inVec.y*scalar)`
`

Reflect velocity only if it is directed towards surface, if it is moving away, don't.

1. If `dot(surfaceNormal, velocity) < 0` ball is moving towards it.
2. If `dot(surfaceNormal, velocity) == 0.0` ball is in parallel to the surface.
3. If `dot(surfaceNormal, velocity) > 0.0` ball is moving away from surface.

Comment: To help me understand this, could you give an example of how this would be used?

Comment: @LukTaylor: ??? "for each object in scene if colliding with wall and velocity is directed toward wall, reflect velocity, otherwise don't"

Answer (score 0):

Here are some simple tricks, that becomes easy to understand. I have used pygame for this . We need some constants like 'frame rate' and displacement of pixels[ball] to visualize the results. What we do is this. Once it hit the walls we change the direction of flow of pixels depends on which side of the wall. [For us it looks like it deflected from wall]
Follow the code.

```
    self.ball     = pygame.Rect(300,PADDLE_Y -  BALL_DIAMETER,BALL_DIAMETER,BALL_DIAMETER)
    self.ball_vel = [10,-10]
    self.ball.left += self.ball_vel[0] 
    self.ball.top  += self.ball_vel[1]
    if self.ball.left <= 0:                  #---1
        self.ball.left = 0
        self.ball_vel[0] = -self.ball_vel[0]
    elif self.ball.left >= MAX_BALL_X:       #---2
        self.ball.left = MAX_BALL_X
        self.ball_vel[0] = -self.ball_vel[0]

    if self.ball.top < 0:                    #---3
        self.ball.top = 0
        self.ball_vel[1] = -self.ball_vel[1]
    elif self.ball.top >= MAX_BALL_Y:        #--4         
        self.ball.top = MAX_BALL_Y 
        self.ball_vel[1] = -self.ball_vel[1]
    # If the ball hits the left wall it has to invert its velocity [Moving left     become right]  ---1  
    # If the ball hits the Right wall it has to invert its velocity [Moving right become left] ---2    
    # If the ball hits the Bottom wall it has to invert its velocity [Moving downwards become upwards] ---3        
    # If the ball hits the Right wall it has to invert its velocity [Moving upwards become downwards] ---4
```